# Are there any known problems that require potential nontermination to solve?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Apart from problems that specifically have to do with Turing machines, like "Simulate a Turing Machine with the given description", are there any problems that require Turing-complete potentially nonterminating recursion?

For example, are there any known non-Turing-machine-related problems that can't be solved in Coq?

Comment: Are you asking for examples of semi-decidable undecidable problems (i.e. a recursively-enumerable and not recursive language?)

Comment: Anything that tries to solve an undecidable problem: showing termination, proving theorems in first/higher-order logic, null pointer analysis...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a system of polynomials with integer coefficients (Diophantine system), find a solution if there is one, or else run forever. Any program which does this must necessarily be partial because the set of solutions of Diophantine systems is a complete c.e. set, see [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem).